# Everytime I use cuda() to remove Variable from CPU to GPU in pytorch,it takes about 5 to 10 minitues

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

I just do this:

```
t = Variable(torch.randn(5))
t =t.cuda()
print(t)
```

but it takes 5 to 10 minitues,everytime.
I used cuda samples to test bandwidth, it's fine.
Then I used pdb to find which takes the most time.
I find in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__`:

```
def _lazy_new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    _lazy_init()
    # We need this method only for lazy init, so we can remove it
    del _CudaBase.__new__
    return super(_CudaBase, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

it takes about 5 minitues in the `return`
I don't know how to solve my problem by these imformation.
My environment is: Ubuntu 16.04 + CUDA 9.1

Answer (score 1):

There’s a cuda version mismatch between the cuda my pytorch was compiled with the cuda I'm running.I divided the official installation commond

> conda install pytorch torchvision cuda90 -c pytorch

into two section：

> conda install -c soumith magma-cuda90
>
> conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith

The second commond installed pytorch-0.2.0 by default,which mathchs CUDA8.0. After I update my pytorch to 0.3.0,this commond only takes one second.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
torch.cuda.synchronize()
t = Variable(torch.randn(5))
t =t.cuda()
print(t)
```

Then, it should be *blazing fast* depending on your GPU memory, at least on every *re-run* it should be.

Comment: Thanks.I try to do this,but the first time takes 435s and the second time takes 440s.....My GPU is GTX1060  6GB. Is there any problem with my GPU?

Comment: This seems to be no obvious change，the second time takes 440s,about 7 minitues....

Comment: I may try to do this,later.Thanks for your advice.